# Pushing a large signed transaction (testnet) using Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to send [a signed transaction](https://gist.github.com/simcity4242/aaa4f6bec0b47dcf4324) using pybitcointools (Python) using the `blockr_pushtx` function, however it consistently returns `Exception: {"status":"fail","data":"Could not push your transaction!","code":500,"message":"Did you sign your transaction?"}`. The signature isn't the issue. It is likely to be an issue with the size of the transaction.

How does one go about pushing a sizable raw transaction (Testnet, in this case, but both mainnet/testnet answers appreciated) without needing to use Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it possible to switch pybitcointools to another service?

Try http://webbtc.com/api/relay The API should be similar (I haven't tested both)

It is also possible to check tx for validity (by send attempt) here: http://webbtc.com/relay_tx

(There are testnet API there, my links are for mainnet)

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about webbtc! I'll try it out! It's not pybitcointools causing the issue: I've tried using the blockr pushtx web page with similar results. So it may be a blockr issue.

Comment: This works FWIW